# TypeError: (0 , next_connect__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, database, web, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to get my data from mongodb after successful connection by NextConnect package but I got this error:

> TypeError: (0 , next_connect__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default) is not a function

my version of nextconnect is  "version": "1.0.0-next.4",

and this my code :

```
import DbConnect from "@/utilis/DbConnect";
import nc from "next-connect";
import Service from "@/models/Service";
 

DbConnect();

const handler = nc();

handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const services = await Service.find({});
    res.status(200).json(services);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching services" });
  }
});

handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  const { title, details, isActive } = req.body;

  const newService = new Service({ title, details, isActive });

  try {
    await newService.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Service added successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error adding service" });
  }
});

export default handler;
```

so please if any help to fetch data at my localhost/api/services

Answer (score 0):

well , there are some changes in the latest version of **next-connect**  to Create an instance Node.js router in `next-connect@1.0.0-next.4`  :
`const router = createRouter();` .

So change your code like this  :

```
import DbConnect from "@/utilis/DbConnect";
import { createRouter } from 'next-connect';
import Service from "@/models/Service";
 

DbConnect();

const router = createRouter();

router.get(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const services = await Service.find({});
    res.status(200).json(services);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching services" });
  }
});

handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  const { title, details, isActive } = req.body;

  const newService = new Service({ title, details, isActive });

  try {
    await newService.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Service added successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error adding service" });
  }
});

export default handler;
```

if you want to keep your code, you have to downgrade **next-connect** to   `next-connect@0.12.0`

Comment: first thank yoy for your effort , still not working but i got this error in terminal :       - error No HTTP methods exported in '.../api/services/route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.

Comment: just keep your code than downgrade **next-connect** if it worked . than upgrade it and follow the changes in the docs of  [next-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect)